# wget works manually but fails in the Chef bash

Tags: bash, chef-recipe

[UPDATED] modified with actual path

I wrote this script to fetch an installation file from AWS S3 bucket. It works manually using wget in terminal but failed in Chef run.

Error:

```
Resolving s3.amazonaws.com... failed: No address associated with hostname.
wget: unable to resolve host address “s3.amazonaws.com”
```

Script:

```
bash 'hp_file' do
  user 'root'
  cwd '/tmp'
  code <<-EOH
  wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/preprod.useast1/Platforms/HP+OM/Software_Operations_Agent_v11.14_Linux_ISO_TC200-88000.iso
  EOH
end
```

Any idea what went wrong? I've read some SO questions about spacing issue, but it doesn't seem to be the cause in my case. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be nothing interesting at the address `https://s3.amazonaws.com/company.com/H+P/installation.iso`... Is this intended?

Comment: That's a DNS failure. Is DNS working?

Comment: @Thomas modified to an actual path

Comment: @EtanReisner If I manually wget the file, it works. So I'm not sure why DNS fails only in Chef run.

Comment: And if you try with `wget 54.231.244.9/preprod.useast1/Platforms/HP+OM/Software_Operations_Agent_v11.14_Linux_ISO_TC200-88000.iso` ?

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it now. Give me 5 minutes. Thank you.

Comment: It works manually on the same machine where chef fails?

Comment: It's just a blind guess to see if the issue is with the DNS or not

Comment: @EtanReisner yes. That's what's confusing me because it's the same machine.

Comment: If you compare the output from `dig s3.amazonaws.com` run manually and run via chef do you see a difference?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry taking so long. Now it doesn't error out, but it just hangs there not able to complete the bash call.

Comment: @EtanReisner I tried dig and it got response : opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43481

Comment: That's not the entire output is it?

Comment: Is white space allowed to preceed EOH? Typically HEREDOC's must be flush to the left margin.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped me. It turned out that chef client.rb has http_proxy missing and it doesn't take global http_proxy setting by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that solved the issue. The chef client did not take the global proxy setting (`$http_proxy` and `$https_proxy`) from the machine. The fix was to modify the client.rb by adding this line:

```
http_proxy 'http://http-proxy.example.com:port'
```